# How to shift arguments while arguments start with -

Tags: bash, shell-script

Say I have a bash function, which is supposed to remove all arguments that start with "-" until it gets to an argument that does not start with "-".

```
gmx(){

  local options=( );

  while [ "${1:0:1}" == "-"  ]; do
    options+=("${1}")
    shift 1;
  done

  echo "first legit arg: $1"
  "$@" # omg will be executed here, like `omg --rolo`
}

gmx -a -f -c omg --rolo
```

this seems to work, but I am wondering if this is a good generic solution to always get 'omg' to be the first "legit" argument. Are there any edge cases that might fail?

In other words -a, -f, -c are all arguments to gmx. Whereas `omg` and everything that follows, will be run in a child process.

Comment: Is the intention to write a wrapper function around an existing command and to determine which is the first non-option argument? Then, no that's not the right way unless the wrapped command only accepts options that don't take arguments. More generally, the only reliable way is to parse the options the same way the wrapped command does.

Comment: the wrapped command should be the first argument that does not start with -. my methodology will work unless you can explain why it wouldnt?

Comment: i dont parse the arguments of the wrapped command, i pass the unparsed arguments to the wrapped command.

Comment: For instance, it you wrapped `sort`, in `sort -o out -n file1 file2` (same as `sort -oout -n file1 file2`), the first non-option argument is `file1`, not `out` which is the argument of the `-o` option

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something or the function's body is incomplete but why would you run the function with options that are not going to be used (`-a --foo -c`)?. And how is `gmx` supposed to be a wrapper function if it basically runs its args as commands? I mean, instead of running `gmx --foo omg --rolo` (where `--foo` seems to do nothing) just run `omg --rolo`. I get the feeling that this is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), but it's possible that I don't clearly understand the purpose of the question.

Comment: In my case, `gmx` is changing the PATH, so that `omg` has updated PATH settings. `gmx` might have arguments that go to it, instead of arguments that go to `omg`. Hope that makes sense. To be very specific, `gmx` is a leaner version of `npx` which is an official NPM tool for Node.js ecosystem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The official and best way is t use the `getopts` builtin to parse the command line options.

See the man page for more information.

A note may be important: `bash` does not support long options.

If you like scripts to deal with long options, you have two shells that support them: `ksh93` and `bosh`. Both shells support long options the way they are supported by the `getopt(3)` function in libc on Solaris. See the bosh man page (currently starting at page 43:

http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/bosh.1.html

```
getopts "f:(file)(input-file)o:(output-file)" OPT
```

supports e.g an option `-f` with an argument and that option has a long option 
alias `--file` and a second alias for this option `--input-file`

ksh93 supports this as well, even though it is not documented in the ksh93 man page.

Comment: `zsh` also has a `zparseopts` to handle long options. I doesn't support the full GNU `getopt_long()` syntax though (not abbreviations for instance). There's a `getopt` in `util-linux` that can be used in any shell to parse GNU getopt_long style options.

Comment: Thank you for the zsh hint. BTW: The `getopt` command is deprecated since 1986.

Comment: I'm talking of the util-linux getopt command, not the traditional one which can't be used reliably.  See `getopts --man` in ksh93 for the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

```
while getopts ':' opt; do
    :    # This is where ordinarily a case statement would be,
         # case $opt in ... esac
         # But we use : as a no-op
done

shift "$(( OPTIND - 1 ))"
printf 'arg: %s\n' "$@"
```

This uses `getopts` to parse the command line options.  The `while` loop will terminate as soon as the first non-option is found, and the `shift` will shift the processed options off of `$@` leaving only the non-option operands in `$@`.

The script

```
#!/bin/sh

gmx () {
    while getopts ':' opt; do
        :
    done

    shift "$(( OPTIND - 1 ))"
    printf 'arg: %s\n' "$@"
}

gmx -a --foo -c omg lol
```

would output

```
arg: omg
arg: lol
```

---

Since you're not interested in what the real options are, you may obviously do a simple loop like

```
for opt do
    case $opt in
        -*) shift ;;
        *)  break
     esac
done

printf 'arg: %s\n' "$@"
```

This loops over all arguments, shifting off each that starts with a dash and ending at the first one that does not start with a dash.

Comment: Would `while [[ $1 == -* ]]; do shift; done` also work?  Not sure which is more efficient.

Comment: @PeterCordes That would work in `bash`, yes.  When it comes to making a handful of pattern matches, I don't think efficiency really is the main issue.

Answer (score 3):

A much simpler solution, if you have control over the way *gmx* is called, is simply to separate arguments to the wrapper from the wrapped command using `--`, as such

```
gmx garg garg garg -- warg warg warg
```

where

- *garg* means an argument used by *gmx*.
- *warg* means an argument sent to *the wrapper*.

If you want the convenience of omitting `--`, you could make it optional, and search for it before trying the "smart" check.

Comment: I have always wondered if `--` is an official bash thing or more of a convention.

Comment: It's more like a GNU convention, which got picked up by other command authors as being useful. Strictly speaking, it has nothing to do with the shell the command is being run in --- bash simply sees the `--` as another argument.

Comment: yeah I figured, thanks for the info, I upvoted your answer